# C# get Label and change text

Tags: c#, winforms, label, controls

I am trying to loop through a list of currencies that I have and change the value of their labels.
I am looping through my currencies but how can I get the label and change its text of each label per currency as per example below.

EUR: 3.5
GBP 1.5
USD 2.5

lbl'item.currency'.Text = rate;

```
foreach (Currency item in new currencies().getAllCurr())
        {

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: LabelControlNAme.Text = "Your value";

Comment: I am guessing you have multiple labels (one for each currency type) How were you planning to link the appropiate currency to the designated label? Showing the structure of the **Currency** class would help greatly, I guess it consists of a string type **name** and a double type **value** field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add controls (Label)  with `id = Currency.Name` (id="EUR"). In loop you can use `Controls.Find` and find this control dynamically.

```
public class Currency
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public decimal Value {get; set;}
}

foreach (List<Currency> item in new currencies().getAllCurr())
        {
          Label tbx = this.Controls.Find(item.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
           tbx.text = item.Value;
        }
```

Comment: labels not text box